Centering first line in Tikz node
You can place multiline text in a tikz node by setting align as follows:
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[align = left] [draw] {
    Title\\
    Content here
  };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

I would like to have the first line, i.e. "Title", to be centered, but both \begin{center}\end{center} and \centering do not work.
My current workaround is to wrap the content in a minipage, but that requires knowing in advance the width the node should have.
Is there a better way to center the first line, still having tikz to calculate the minimum width required be its content?

Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with \documentclass{...}, the required \usepackage's, \begin{document}, and \end{document}. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for the users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Are you looking for align = center?

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz no, I want to center only the first line and have the rest to be left aligned.

For both the tabular and the varwidth environment (from the varwidth package), you don't have to provide a text width. They stretch as needed. Well, varwidth accepts a maximum text width but we can give it a length that surely will be long enough.
With tabular we use \multicolumn to center the first line while with varwidth the \centering command works as expected.
Code
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\begin{document}
\tikz
  \node[draw] {
    \begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}
      \multicolumn{1}{@{}c@{}}{Title} \\
      Content here \\
      Even more content
    \end{tabular}
  };

\tikz
  \node[draw] {
    \begin{varwidth}{\linewidth}
      {\centering Title \par}
      Content here \\
      Even more content
    \end{varwidth}
  };

\tikz
  \node[draw] {
    \begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}
      \multicolumn{1}{@{}c@{}}{A Very Very Long Title} \\
      Content here \\
      Even more content
    \end{tabular}
  };

\tikz
  \node[draw] {
    \begin{varwidth}{\linewidth}
      {\centering A Very Very Long Title \par}
      Content here \\
      Even more content
    \end{varwidth}
  };
\end{document}


You could use a multipart node:
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[align = left,draw,rectangle split,rectangle split ignore empty parts,rectangle split draw splits=false] {
    Title
    \nodepart{two}
    Content here\\
    Content
  };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



Unless it's A Very Long Title (but then everything could simply be left-aligned). The space between the first and second line is also a bit more than usual …

@Qrrbrbirlbel If the title is longer than the content, the whole concept of centring the first line sounds strange :)

@Qrrbrbirlbel maybe you want to remove the column padding in your tabular approach to deal with the very long title: \multicolumn{1}{@{}c@{}}{A Very Long Title which is longer than it should be}

I don't see any difference between @{}c@{} and just c with \multicolumn.

@Qrrbrbirlbel With just c I get https://i.sstatic.net/fxVLk86t.png (for classes other than minimal)

Ah, the class minimal makes the difference here. It leaves \tabcolsep at 0pt.

@Qrrbrbirlbel Thinking about it, you could set the tabcolsep at the start of your node and then you don't need all the @{}
